# How to Disable CSS for a particular field

Tags: css

I am using a styling for all the input fields but there is one field for which i do not want that style. Is there any way i can disable the css for that particular field and let it be for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a css class to that element and use [:not](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp) pseudo-class selector:

```css
input:not(.notred) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<input name="text1">
<input name="text2">
<input name="text3">
<input class="notred" name="text4">
<input name="text5">
<input name="text6">
```

Comment: it Works!!Thanks!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

In CSS3, you can use ‘:not()’ to exclude an element using id or class.

Answer (score 1):

add a class to that input which you want to disable, then in css

```
input:not(.that_class)
```

Let me know if you have any issue.